# How to combine column data which have same column headers

Tags: python

I am trying to combine columns' data having the same column header inside the same data frame.

Current version

| **FIDB** | RECOM | HDBAS | ADFDS | RECOM | ADFDS | HDBAS | HDBAS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ISIN** | INE0212 | INE752 | INE862 | INE943 | INE004 | INE035 | INE143 |
| **MDat** | 6/30 2 | 6/29 22 | 6/28 22 | 6/16 2 | 6/1222 | 6/15222 | 6/14 |

Required version-

```
      REC     |      HDB       |       ADF    
------------------------------------------------
ISN   | Mdate |  ISN   | Mdate | ISN   |  Mdate
------------------------------------------------
INE02   6/30  |  INE75   6/29  | INE86    6/28  
INE94   6/16  |  INE03   6/14  | INE00    6/12
```

*ignore the incorrect values.....but follow the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data ='''\
FIDB,RECOM,HDBAS,ADFDS,RECOM,ADFDS,HDBAS,HDBAS
ISIN,INE0212,INE752,INE862,INE943,INE004,INE035,INE143
MDat,6/30 2,6/29 22,6/28 22,6/16 2,6/1222,6/15222,6/14
'''

file = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0, header=None).T.set_index('FIDB')

groups = {}
for name, group in df.groupby(level=0):
    groups[name] = group.reset_index(drop=True)

output = pd.concat(groups, axis=1)
```

[image]